# What are the parameters for using bfg

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner

I am trying to clean something out of my git repo using [bfg](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). The author's instructions suggest

```
java -jar bfg --replace-text passwords.txt  my-repo.git
```

I understood these to mean

```
java -jar bfg.jar --replace-text <some text?> <a directory?>
```

But all my efforts to provide a text and a directory get an error `Error: Option --replace-text failed when given 'some-text'. some-text (No such file or directory)`. Has anyone worked out how use bfg?

My aim is to remove a short string from my history (probably only appearing in one file but I can't be sure of that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner` issue 154](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/154#issuecomment-221590263) provides the following example:

> So you create a *file* called, e.g. `replacements.txt`, and put stuff like this in it - one line per password, credential, etc:
>
> ```
> PASSWORD1 # Replace literal string 'PASSWORD1' with '***REMOVED***' (default)
> PASSWORD2==>examplePass         # replace with 'examplePass' instead
> PASSWORD3==>                    # replace with the empty string
> regex:password=\w+==>password=  # Replace, using a regex
> ```
>
> ...then you run the BFG, specifying the file of replacements:
>
> ```
> $ java -jar bfg.jar  --replace-text replacements.txt  my-repo.git
> ```

You should put your short string into a test file.